# How I can find the angular orbital velocity of satellite in circle orbit?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, artificial-satellite, calculation

I know that we have the angular orbital velocity of a satellite in circle orbit as $w_0=\frac{v}{r}$, but I want another way to find out the angular orbital velocity of a satellite in the circle orbit.

Comment: See if [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_orbit) helps.

Comment: This here might be of interest: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=KdHI5Fn9Fu8&t=363s&pp=ygUiaG9obWFubiB0cmFuc2ZlciBvcmJpdCBjYWxjdWxhdGlvbg%3D%3D

Comment: This is a good question! In your example $v$ is a scalar velocity and it is the *component* of the vector velocity perpendicular to the radial direction. There is a good answer to this question as written and it should not be closed. **voting to leave open** so that that good answer can be posted and not prevented.

Comment: @uhoh since a circular orbit is specified, all of the velocity is in the tangential/horizontal direction anyway

Comment: @ErinAnne OP asks for "another way" so the full equation, starting from a state vector would count. Yes it can be reduced to the given equation, but they're not the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

per [Kepler's third law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion#Third_law)

> The ratio of the square of an object's orbital period with the cube of the semi-major axis of its orbit is the same for all objects orbiting the same primary.

You've specified the orbit is circular, so the semi-major axis (typically $a$) is just the orbital radius $r$.

The derivation in the link above from Newton's law of gravitation to Kepler's Third Law is pretty straightforward and I won't reproduce it here.  But as the [Wikipedia page on Circular orbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_orbit) that AJN's comment linked to notes, you can rearrange to

$\omega^2 r^3 = \mu$

where $\mu$ is the [standard gravitational parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravitational_parameter) of whatever the satellite is orbiting.  Solve for

$\omega = \sqrt{\mu/r^3}$

Ensure that you pay attention to the units of $\mu$ to get sensible results.

I suspect the close votes would be withdrawn if you're clear about which information you have available to try to derive the angular rate from. Since you utilized the radius in the question this seemed like the obvious place to start.